# What is the difference between WinJS.Binding.mixin and WinJS.Binding.dynamicObservableMixin?

Tags: windows-8, winjs, mixins

In WinJS there are three binding related mixins:

- WinJS.Binding.observableMixin
- [WinJS.Binding.dynamicObservableMixin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700607.aspx)
- [WinJS.Binding.mixin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211859.aspx)

Both WinJS.Binding.mixin and WinJS.Binding.dynamicObservableMixin define the same methods to mix. The **only difference** between their definition is that WinJS.Binding.mixin is defined as a non enumerable property on the WinJS.Binding namespace, while WinJS.Binding.dynamicObservableMixin is defined as an enumerable property:

```
WinJS.Namespace.define("WinJS.Binding", {
    mixin: { value: dynamicObservableMixin, enumerable: false, writable: true, configurable: true },
    dynamicObservableMixin: { value: dynamicObservableMixin, enumerable: true, writable: true, configurable: true },
});
```

I don't see any real difference between these two mixins - I don't see the relevance of the difference of the enumerable flag on this property. Is there any semantic or other difference as to which mixin of the two one is using?

Answer (score 1):

You are right. There is no real difference between `mixin` and `dynamicObservableMixin`. They are same.

`WinJS.Binding.mixin` adds methods like addProperty, removeProperty, get/setProperty which are used by `WinJS.Binding.expandProperties`. expandProperties is used to make an existing class observable. dynamic nature is attributed to dynamically adding properties to an object.

Example:

```
var MyListViewModel = WinJS.Class.define(
    function MyListViewModel_ctor()
    {
        this._initObservable();
    },
    {
        load: function load()
        {
            var self = this;
            return serviceclient.getMyListData().then(function (records)
            {
                self.items = new WinJS.Binding.List(records);
            });
        }
    });

WinJS.Class.mix(MyListViewModel,
    WinJS.Binding.mixin,
    WinJS.Binding.expandProperties({ items: '' }));
```

There is difference between `observableMixin` and `mixin`. `observableMixin` only has `bind`, `unbind` and `notify` methods.